# How to persist Grails objects to DB managed outside of Grails

Tags: grails, persistence

I'm new to Grails and was wondering if there was a way to populate some of my domain classes from web services rather than the DB managed by Grails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RxGORM for REST is designed for exactly this task:

http://gorm.grails.org/latest/rx/rest-client/manual/index.html

Comment: Thanks Graeme, this seems to be just what I was looking for. My IDE doesn't seem to want to pull the dependency although I can see that it's in the repository.

Comment: Graeme, do you have an sample implementation of this?

Comment: Sure see here https://github.com/grails/gorm-rest-client/tree/master/examples/grails31-simple

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Had some trouble with the returned JSON but I opened a new question on that. Thanks for your help.